# x86 assembly instruction: call *Reg

Tags: assembly, x86, call

Can anybody give me some information about indirect function calls in x86 assembly, i.e. instructions like

```
call *Reg
```

So where the address of the function label is stored in a register. Somehow I couldn't find information about it via google.

And furthermore, what does it mean if I get a Trace/breakpoint exception when running an x86 assembly program which has such an instruction?

Comment: http://felixcloutier.com/x86/CALL.html

Answer (score 10):

Intel and AMD publish very good documentation regarding x86.
Here's a link to Intels instruction set reference which (of course) has a section on CALL.
http://www.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/243191.HTM

```
OP Code: FF /2 
Instruction: CALL r/m32 
Description: Call near, absolute indirect, address given in r/m32
```

Using NASM syntax

```
lbl_start:
 MOV EAX, lbl_function1
 CALL EAX
 RETN

lbl_function1:
 MOV EAX, 1
 RET 0
```

If you're getting an exception it could mean almost anything. Here's a few common issues...

- you're not setting the register to an address within the program

  - you're setting the register value but it's being changed by an API call that happens before your CALL reg32
  - you're setting the register value to the data located at a specific address rather than the address itself
- you're encoding your CALL reg32 OP Code  incorrectly, (ex: FF D0 is CALL EAX in hex)